# How to get values in Excel from the column where value equals to the specific number?

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 sheets, in first - all the Data. In the second i want to show only values that i want. Something like: IF value from column "B" of 1st sheet = 1, show values from column C and D in 2nd sheet.

[Here i need to select all values that equals, for example "503" in the column L, and show them all in the 2nd sheet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gC5kR.jpg)

How can i do this?

Comment: Use filters then copy and paste.  Turn on the macro recorder then look at the code and clean it up.

Comment: Yeah I suggest do what Scott said, but first make sure your data is in a table, then wen you have the table selected, hit ctrl+l I think is to bring up the filters, then from there you can add in 3 different types of filters based on the data type, namely, caption filters, for text, numeric filters for numbers, and date filters for dates... Be careful not to insert rows into a filtered table as you probably will regret the positioning when you clear the filter.

Comment: Got an answer for you but I have to wait 3 minutes to post again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or here's a little code snippet of comparing two sheets cells, same of different (up to you) and if they match, to place them in sheet 2's column L1 :

```
Sub TEST()
Dim value1 As String
Dim value2 As String
value1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value 'sheet 1 value
value2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("b1").Value 'sheet 2 value
If value1 = value2 Then
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("L1").Value = value1 'or 2
Else
MsgBox ("Values do not match!" + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + "'" + value1 + "'" + "does not match '" + value2 + "'.")
End If
End Sub
```

[image]

If you want to tweak it to your liking, change sheet 1's value, or sheet 2's, your call.

Happy coding :)

Comment: Pleasure David! :) Hope my answer answers your question?